# mysql join query with sum retuns null

Tags: mysql, join, sum

If makale_payments table is null the query returns null. How shoul i set the query yo get recors if doesnt exist in SUM(`payment_total`) like 0.00 ?

```
SELECT article_name,user_real_name,user_name,SUM(`article_payment`) as holding,paid
FROM makale_articles AS t1
JOIN makale_users ON (t1.article_name=makale_users.user_id) 
JOIN (SELECT user_id,SUM(`payment_total`) as paid FROM makale_payments GROUP BY user_id) AS t2 ON (t1.article_name=t2.user_id)
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not return aggregate values for rows that return nulls, even if specifically testing for ISNULL.  ISNULL is only to check if a column is null, not if the relation returns null.  I did however find a (albeit very obscure) way to get around this limitation.  The basic premise is to union all two sql statements and use the two unioned query as a subquery to select from.

The unioned queryies would be of the form:

```
   select column1, column2, SUM(column3) as payment from tablea, tableb where....
   union all
   select column1, column2, 0.00 as payment from tablea --notice no join, and a specified value and alias for aggregate column
```

With the above query, you will get two rows for every row that the relation is not null, and one row when it is.  If you sum that rows and group by, then you should end up with the values you want.  So you then create a query that uses the above as the table to select from and sums the aggregate column:

```
   select column1, column2, SUM(payment) from

   (select column1, column2, SUM(column3) as payment from tablea, tableb where....
   union all
   select column1, column2, 0.00 as payment from tablea) as b
   group by column1, column2
```

I am probably off on the syntax of the query, sorry, I don't have MySQL here to test.

Answer (score 1):

This is what `IFNULL` is for:

```
IFNULL(SUM(...), 0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

`article_payment` is probably `NULL` for some row. Try this:

```
SELECT 
    article_name,
    user_real_name,
    user_name,
    SUM(COALESCE(`article_payment`, 0)) as holding,
    paid
FROM article_articles AS t1
JOIN article_users ON (t1.article_name=article_users.user_id) 
JOIN (
    SELECT user_id, SUM(COALESCE(`payment_total`, 0)) as paid 
    FROM article_payments 
    GROUP BY user_id
) AS t2 ON (t1.article_name=t2.user_id)
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

Comment: @dr.linux - I've seen your sqlfiddle, my query seems to be working (after updating table names with 'makale_'): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cd06/12

Comment: article_payments is not null please clear data in the table and try the query.

Comment: @dr.linux Sorry, but I don't understand you. If the table is empty, you don't get a row with a `NULL` value, you get zero rows. If that's not what you mean, please setup a sqlfiddle with the exact database situation and query you want to describe.

Comment: I want to if article_payments table null or there is no data for article_name user get payment_total as 0.00

Answer (score 0):

A simple WHERE wouldn't have hurt I guess

```
WHERE SUM(`article_payment`) > 0
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE SUM(`article_payment`) > 0 LIMIT 0, 30' at line 5

Comment: try this `WHERE SUM(t1.article_payment) > 0`

Comment: Why dont you create a schema on sqlfiddle.com instead? I cam certainly give a working query then :)